# Proving a quotient of a free group is also a free group - Wirtinger presentation

Tags: group-theory, knot-theory, free-groups, group-presentation

I am reading about Wirtinger presentations for knot groups but I am confused about how the Wirtinger presentation is preserved by the Reideimester moves. More specifically, I'm looking into a simple example, namely proving that $\langle x,y\rangle$ and $\langle x,y,z\mid z=xyx^{-1}\rangle$ are isomorphic which I get from applying a Type 2 Reideimester move to two trivial knots. I'm probably just really rusty on my group theory but I would appreciate any help!

Comment: The second group is the first group where you've got a notational shorthand that every time you see $xyx^{-1}$ you can abbreviate it with $z$.

Comment: This is an instance of a *Tietze transformation*, which you might want to learn about more generally.